# formGroup expects a formGroup instance, how to properly assign the formcontrol names

Tags: forms, angular, ionic-framework

I am really new to angular2 and ionic. so i am trying to implement a form that takes in values and will be submitted to a service. i am getting the error:

```
Error in ./RecordvisitPage class RecordvisitPage - caused by: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

here is my html page:

```
<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="recordVisitForm">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Action Date</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="actionDate" name="actionDate"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Contacted</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="contacted" name="contacted"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
 </form>
<ion-footer>
  <button ion-button navPop>Back</button>
  <button ion-button (click)="saveVisit()">Save</button>
</ion-footer>
```

so the component attatched to this html page is :

```
public recordVisitForm: FormGroup;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private  loanService : LoanService,  public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public params: NavParams) { 

    this.loan = params.get('loan');

    this.recordVisitForm = formBuilder.group({
      actionDate: ['', Validators.required],
      contacted: ['', Validators.required],

    });

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `this` in `formbuilder.group...`

```
this.recordVisitForm = this.formBuilder.group({ // here
  actionDate: ['', Validators.required],
  contacted: ['', Validators.required],

});
```

Comment: yea sure... i tried to but it didn't let me (i have to wait for 6 min or so in order to vote it as an answer)